# Stop / Remove a <script> tag from loading within a php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is this possible to do with php within the same file? I want to try to exclude a  tag and everything within it from loading on .php page.

Was thinking something like `preg_replace('~<\s*\bscript\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*\/\s*script\s*>~is', '', $var);` but not sure how that would be implemented within the .php file.

Essentially the file is loading a script that I want to exclude. I can modify the file, but I cannot remove the script tag.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is preprocessed, you can always encapsulate the `script` tag in an "if statement".

```
<?php if ($something) { ?> <script></script> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: That is a good idea, unfortunately I am not able to encapsulate it, it must be on its own.

Comment: Could you give some context to what platform you're using?

Comment: @thamind What do mean "it must be on its own"